# Conditional delete from Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-adapter

Sorry in advance if my question sounds silly. I am a newby.
In my app I have an adapter which shows the documents queried from Firebase Firestore.
At the moment there is a OnSwipe listener which can delete documents.
I want to set it the way that the only documents which were recorded by the certain user can be deleted. Meaning: user can only delete documents writen by him and cannot delete documents written by others.
Please advise how to do this?

At the moment the code looks like this:

```
new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: please provide the content of the method `deleteItem()` and also the data structure of the "document"

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Thank you guys. Not sure how to add screenshot here. 
The deleteItem() is the following:
 public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement security rules to restrict the delete operation to the author of the document. In this document[1], it mentions how to set rules for write, which also contains create, update, and delete rules [2] . So you can set a rule like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read; 
            allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userid;
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, it would be clearer if you could provide the contents of deleteitem(), and the document structure.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query
[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not sure how to show document structure here. 
Each document has some fields and one if them is userID, which can also be null.

  public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.
I did modify my delete method and it worked:
Thank you for your hints and help

```
 public void deleteItem(int position, String userID) {
    String docUserID = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getString("userID");
    Log.i("deleteItem", "docUserID: " + docUserID + " userID: " + userID);
    if (docUserID != null) {
        if (docUserID.equals(userID)) {
            getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
            Log.i("deleteItem", " if worked... ");

        } else {
            Log.i("deleteItem", " if did not work");
        }
    }

}
```